# Javascript Onchange function in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

my template file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title>New Order</title>
     
</head>
<body>


    {%extends "base.html"%}
    {%block content%}

<br>
    <form id="sform" class=" mb-3 container" method="post">
        <div class="row">
    <span id="innout" class="">

                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Customers</label>
                  <select class="form-select" name = "client" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                    <option selected>Choose</option>
                    {%for customer in customers%}
                    <option value={{customer.name}}>{{customer.name}}</option>
                    {%endfor%}
                    {%for supplier in suppliers%}
                    <option value={{supplier}}>{{supplier}}</option>
                    {%endfor%}
                  </select>
                </div>
            <br>
             <div class="input-group-text my-2 ">
                <input class="form-check-input mt-0" id="in" type="radio" value="in" name="IO" required aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                <label for="in">In</label>
            </div>
            
            <div class="input-group-text my-2">
                <input class="form-check-input mt-0" id="out" type="radio" value="out" name="IO"  aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                <label for="out">Out</label>
            </div>
                
    </span>

    {%for i in index%}
    {%if i == 0 or i==11 or i==21  %}
        <div id = itemstock class="col">
    {%endif%}
                <div id="{{items[i].code}}">
                    <div class="input-group my-1">
                      <input id="{{items[i].name}}" name="{{items[i].name}}" type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Dollar amount (with dot and two decimal places)" value="0" min="0" onchange="total()">
                      <span class="input-group-text">{{items[i].stock}}</span>
                      <span class="input-group-text">{{items[i].name}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        

    
    {%if i == 10 or i==20 or i==30 %}   
    </div>
    {%endif%}
    {%endfor%}
    <span id="ttl">
<input type="date" name="today" class="form-control" value="{{date}}">
    </span>
    </div>

    

    <div class="row">
            <div class="input-group mb-3 my-5 ">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Total</span>
      <input id="total" type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">

    </div>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto ">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" onclick="submit()" >
            <button id="calc" class="btn btn-primary" >Calculate</button>
        </div>
        </div>

    </form>

    <p class = "dump" style="display: none"> {{dump}}</p>
    {%endblock content%}

</body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='main.js')}}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        items = JSON.parse(document.querySelector(".dump").innerHTML)

        var total = function(){
            let numtotal = 0
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                document.querySelector("#"+items[i].name).addEventListener("change",total())
                numtotal = numtotal + parseInt(document.querySelector("#"+items[i].name).value,10)*items[i].price
                 
         }
            document.querySelector("#total").value = numtotal
        }


      </script>

 
</html>
```

my js file:

```
    items = JSON.parse(document.querySelector(".dump").innerHTML)
    
    var total = function(){
        let numtotal = 0
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            document.querySelector("#"+items[i].name).addEventListener("change",total())
            numtotal = numtotal + parseInt(document.querySelector("#"+items[i].name).value,10)*items[i].price
             
     }
        document.querySelector("#total").value = numtotal
    }
```

[image: here you can see that although I can call the function in the console, it still does not get activated at onchange]

The onchange is not working. although I can call the function in the console, it doesn't work on the screen. even tried copy pasting the code into a script tag. even tried using event listener function.
According to the first options, i changed the onchange to an eventlistener but that doesnt seem to work. I'm pretty sure the file is properly linked and the Json is getting converted, because when i call the function in the console it runs properly and gives me the total in the input box.

Comment: In the `onchange` attribute, `total` is the `total` property of the `form` element (which is the input with `id=total`) and not a function. You aren't accessing the global variable you assigned the function to. `on*` attributes are awful. Don't use them. Use `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  items = JSON.parse(document.querySelector(".dump").innerHTML)

    var total = function(){
        let numtotal = 0
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            document.querySelector("#"+items[i].name).addEventListener("onchange",total)
            numtotal = numtotal + parseInt(document.querySelector("#"+items[i].name).value,10)*items[i].price
             
     }
        document.querySelector("#total").value = numtotal
    }
})`

do you mean something like this ?
This is not working as well

Comment: and the amazing thing is that the function works perfectly when I call it in the console. it just shows up as an error when I actually change something in my input fields with the onchange assigned to them.

Comment: The event name is `change` not `onchange`

Comment: I tried it, it's still not working though. I've edited my question so you can get a better picture